# Grouping rows by "name" from one table and ordering by "timestamp" from other table in a many-to-many relationship with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following 3 MySQL tables, 'posts' can have many players and many 'players' can have many 'posts'. These two are linked together with the `players_posts_links` table. Each player's name is unique.

```
`posts`
| id  | title             | timestamp  |
|-----|-------------------|------------|
| 1   | Hello world       | 2020-09-16 |
| 2   | My favorite songs | 2020-07-01 |
| 3   | Another post      | 2023-04-01 |
| 4   | Gaming together   | 2023-05-03 |

`players`
| id  | name |
|-----|------|
| 1   | John |
| 2   | Jane |
| 3   | Mark |

`players_posts_links`
| id  | player_id | post_id |
|-----|-----------|---------|
| 1   | 1         | 3       |
| 2   | 2         | 1       |
| 3   | 2         | 2       |
| 4   | 3         | 4       |
| 5   | 1         | 4       |
```

I want to retrieve only the most recent post for each player. When executing the following query below, it does not always return the most recent post by a player.

```sql
SELECT players.name, any_value(posts.title)
FROM posts
         LEFT JOIN players_posts_links link on posts.id = link.post_id
         LEFT JOIN players on link.player_id = players.id
GROUP BY players.name
ORDER BY max(posts.timestamp) DESC
```

The expected result should be:

```
| posts.id | posts.title     | players.name |
|----------|-----------------|--------------|
| 4        | Gaming together | John         |
| 4        | Gaming together | Mark         |
| 1        | Hello world     | Jane         |
```

Comment: Try converting your timestamp into an INTEGER by using Unix_Timestamp and then you can compare with the MAX command correctly, because it would compare the highest number and not have to figure out date issues.  See this post here for details on how to do that.  If this works, let me know and I will type up a real answer.  -->
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515752/how-to-get-unix-timestamp-in-mysql-from-utc-time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: @easleyfixed I changed the query to the following to convert the timestamp to a unix timestamp, but the results remain the same, i.e. not always the most recent post by a player is returned: 

```SELECT players.name, any_value(posts.title)
FROM posts
         LEFT JOIN players_posts_links link on posts.id = link.post_id
         LEFT JOIN players on link.player_id = players.id
GROUP BY players.name
ORDER BY MAX(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(tumblr_timestamp, '+00:00', @@global.time_zone))) DESC;
```

Comment: Hmm that is strange if that didn't fix the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT po.title, 
           po.timestamp, 
           ppl.player_id, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ppl.player_id ORDER BY po.timestamp DESC) rn
    FROM posts po
    JOIN players_posts_links ppl on po.id = ppl.post_id
)
SELECT cte.title, 
       cte.timestamp, 
       pl.name 
FROM cte 
JOIN players pl on cte.player_id = pl.id
WHERE cte.rn = 1;
```